# npm start stop with exit status 3 : Failed to exec start script [Angular]

Tags: node.js, angular, npm

I'm new on Angular and I have to work on a project in this technology.I set up the project but when I run the `npm start` command, the process `npm start` stop suddenly : the `ng serve`  fails. I tried to investigate but I found nothing that can fix my problem.

You can see the errors here : [errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jIp6u.png)

npm version : 6.14.11

node version : v14.15.5

Dependencies in the package.json file :

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^11.0.3",
    "@angular/cdk": "^11.0.1",
    "@angular/common": "~11.0.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "~11.0.3",
    "@angular/core": "~11.0.3",
    "@angular/flex-layout": "^11.0.0-beta.33",
    "@angular/forms": "~11.0.3",
    "@angular/material": "^11.0.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~11.0.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~11.0.3",
    "@angular/platform-server": "~11.0.3",
    "@angular/router": "~11.0.3",
    "@angular/service-worker": "^11.0.3",
    "@ngx-prism/core": "^2.0.1",
    "@syncfusion/ej2-angular-richtexteditor": "^18.3.52",
    "@types/prismjs": "^1.16.2",
    "@types/socket.io-client": "^1.4.34",
    "angular-http-server": "^1.9.0",
    "app-root-path": "^3.0.0",
    "chart.js": "^2.9.4",
    "compodoc": "0.0.41",
    "core-js": "^3.8.0",
    "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
    "http-server": "^0.12.3",
    "http-status": "^1.5.0",
    "jquery": "^3.5.1",
    "ngx-captcha": "^8.0.1",
    "ngx-countdown": "^11.0.0",
    "ngx-countdown-timer": "^0.2.0",
    "ngx-drag-drop": "^2.0.0",
    "ngx-json-viewer": "^2.4.0",
    "ngx-mat-select-search": "^3.1.4",
    "ngx-pipes": "^2.7.5",
    "ngx-socket-io": "^3.2.0",
    "prismjs": "^1.22.0",
    "rxjs": "^6.6.3",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.6.3",
    "socket.io-client": "^3.0.3",
    "xls": "^0.5.1",
    "xlsx": "^0.16.9",
    "zone.js": "^0.11.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.1100.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^11.0.3",
    "@compodoc/compodoc": "^1.1.11",
    "@types/chart.js": "^2.9.28",
    "@types/jasmine": "3.6.2",
    "@types/node": "^14.14.10",
    "@types/source-map": "^0.5.7",
    "@types/webpack": "^4.41.25",
    "typescript": "~4.0.0"
  }
```

Do you have an idea ?

I tried to run :

```
npm cache clean --force
npm install
npm start
```

But that don't help me.